# How to programmatically check WiFi Debugging is enabled on Android 11+ phone?

Tags: android, debugging, xamarin.android, adb, android-wifi

`Settings.Global.ADB_ENABLED` flag is only responsive for USB debugging. Is there an alternative for checking WiFi debugging in Developer options is enabled programmatically?

Device is not rooted. `su` commands will not work.

Comment: Do you want to know if your phone is connected via wifi?
Then , you can use [Xamarin.Essentials: Connectivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/connectivity?tabs=android) to achieve this.

Comment: No, I want to know if Wifi Debugging option is enabled in Developer options, basically.

Comment: I am looking same solution, Have you got answer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [detect wireless debugging option active or not in developer mode in android programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73990443/detect-wireless-debugging-option-active-or-not-in-developer-mode-in-android-prog)