# detect wireless debugging option active or not in developer mode in android programmatically

Tags: android, adb, android-wifi, android-wireless, adbwireless

I have tried developer mode and USB debugging is enabled or not,

using the below code changes. it's working fine.

`private fun check_My_Android_Mobile_Developer_Mode_Status() {`

// solution 1

```
val adb: Int = Settings.Secure.getInt(this.contentResolver,
            Settings.Global.ADB_ENABLED, 0)

        Toast.makeText(this,"USB Debugging Detect: adb mode:"+adb, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

// solution 2

```
    if(Settings.Secure.getInt(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS_ENABLED, 0) == 1) {
        // Developer Mode enabled
        Toast.makeText(this,"Developer Mode enabled: Show Alert", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    } else {
        //Developer Mode does not enabled
        Toast.makeText(this,"Developer does not enabled: Running Safe Mode", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

But, I want to check wireless debug mode is enabled or not alone(from developer mode On status). I unable to find any solution.

can anyone help on this. Thanks Advance. Referred links below:

[how-to-check-usb-debugging-enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18716808/how-to-check-usb-debugging-enabled-programmatically)

[wireless-adb-android-11](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#wireless-adb-android-11)

[android-detect-when-adb-active-over-usb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16741787/android-detect-when-adb-active-over-usb)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android source code reveals the wifi debugging setting: https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:packages/apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings/development/WirelessDebuggingEnabler.java;l=73?q=wireless%20debugging

`Settings.Global.ADB_WIFI_ENABLED = "adb_wifi_enabled"`

```kotlin
fun isWifiAdbEnabled(): Boolean {
    // "this" is your activity or context
    return Settings.Global.getInt(this.contentResolver, "adb_wifi_enabled", 0) != 0
}
```

Usage:

```kotlin
Toast.makeText(this, "adb mode: ${isWifiAdbEnabled()}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

Comment: I tested on an Android 11 device and it works for me

Comment: I tested on Android 12 device and it works for me too